# Should UIAlertView be subclassed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview

I am sure the answer to this is "**no**" as the documentation is very clear. But I am a little confused. A standard `UIAlertView` is pretty dull and I want to improve the look and it seems that other apps do it (see the example below).

Another possibility is that they are not subclassed `UIAlertViews`. In which case, how is this achieved?

The page [UIAlertViews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIAlertView) states

> Appearance of Alert Views
>
> You cannot customize the appearance of alert views.

So how do we get the something like the example shown here?

[image]

Comment: "The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing" - in theory. This means that you should not subclass it. (However, I doubt that it **cannot** be done -- it's just a class, you certainly **can** technically inherit another class from it, but it's a bad idea.)

Comment: I can do it and I have done, but I am asking how the above gets done if Apple say 'No' to subclassing.

Comment: Apple _may_ use a private subclass of `UIAlertView` then subclass `UIAlertView` won't help much.

Comment: To completely have similar behavior you also have to create an alert UIWindow.

Answer (score 4):

No, do not subclass it. From the docs:

> **Subclassing Notes**
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is
> and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is
> private and must not be modified.

What you can do though is create a UIView and have it act similar to a UIAlertView. It's isn't very difficult and seems to be what they are doing in your op.

Comment: Thank you. Is that what they have done here in my example would you say?

Comment: Yes I believe so, it seems a bit over the top to be a subclassed UIAlertview.

Answer (score 3):

Apple's docs say that you should not subclass it. That means that there are probably internal reasons that would make it difficult to make it work right.

You might or might not be able to make a subclass of UIAlertView work, but you do so at your own risk, and future iOS releases might break you without warning. If you tried to complain Apple would laugh and tell you "I told you so".

Better to create a view that looks and acts like an alert but is your own custom view/view controller. Beware that even this is dangerous, because Apple has been making sweeping changes to the look and feel of it's UI elements recently. If you implement a view controller that looks and acts like a variant of the current alert view, Apple could change that look and/or behavior in the future and your UI app would end up looking odd and outdated. We've been bitten by this sort of thing before.

Comment: I appreciate your advice. So do I just stick with with dull ones Apple give us? Seems a shame.

Comment: Pretty much, yes. Dull is at least consistent and familiar.

Answer (score 3):

Rethink your strategy. Why do you need to use an Alert View? Besides having a modal view displayed top-most on your view stack, there's not much else that it does. Instead, subclass UIView or UIViewController to define your own interface, using images and ui elements to give it the style and input functionality as needed.

I usually subclass UIView, and attach it to the app's window's view so that I'm certain that it will be displayed on top of anything else. And you can use blocks to provide hooks into the various input elements of your new view (did user press OK, or did user enter text?)

For example:

```
// Instantiate your custom alert
UIView *myCustomAlert = [[UIMyCustomUIViewAlert alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)];

// Suppose the new custom alert has a completion block for when user clicks on some button
// Or performs some action...
myCustomAlert.someEventHandler = ^{
    // This block should be invoked internally by the custom alert view
    // in response to some given user action.
};

// Display your custom alert view
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[window addSubview: myCustomAlert];

// Make sure that your custom alert view is top-most
[window bringSubviewToFront: myCustomAlert];
```

Using this method, however, will not pause the thread's execution like UIAlertView does. Using this method, everything will continue running as usual. So if you need to pause execution while your custom alert is showing, then it gets much trickier.

But otherwise, creating your own custom alerts is quite straightforward, just as you would customize any other view. You could even use Interface Builder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is a great help and thank you for the time you have taken to answer.

Comment: Here's a custom implementation of an alert view (based on UIView): https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview

Answer (score 2):

**No.** You absolutely should **not** subclass a `UIAlertView` for any reason. [Apple explicitly states](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) this in their documentation (see "Subclassing Notes"). They even tell you that it relies on *private methods* - and we all know that meddling in private methods in an AppStore app is immediate grounds for rejection.

**HOWEVER**, there isn't a need to subclass `UIAlertView` on iOS 7. Apple introduced a new Custom ViewController Transitions feature in iOS 7.0 that lets you present completely custom ViewControllers with completely custom transitions. In other words, you could very easily make your own UIAlertView or even something better. There's a nice tutorial on the new feature [here](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/):

[image]

In fact, there are lots of good tutorials on this - a quick [Google search on the topic](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=custom+transitions+ios+7&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) turns up a huge wealth of information.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate that. Sadly I am still stuck on Xcode 4.6 as iMac is too old for Xcode 5 needed for iOS 7 etc etc But I will take a look - cheers.

Comment: You may be able to do something like that with iOS 6 modal view controllers... although I doubt it is more flexible, and it would definitely be "*hacky*".